# How do I make all silences in an audio file be of equal length (e.g. 1 second)? "My name is Bob [1s] I like ice cream [1s]..."

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

How do I make all silences in an audio file be of equal length (e.g. 1 second)?

- Before: My name is Bob [0.5s] I like ice cream [2s] and I like music [4s] I also enjoy...
- After: My name is Bob [1s] I like ice cream [1s] and I like music [1s] I also enjoy...

Alternative if it's not possible, how can I add 1 second to all silences?

- Before: My name is Bob [0.5s] I like ice cream [2s] and I like music [4s] I also enjoy...
- After: My name is Bob [1.5s] I like ice cream [3s] and I like music [5s] I also enjoy...

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show where you are getting stuck when using e g. `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I'm not sure ffmpeg can do it

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/579008/302907

Comment: @Anaksunaman I know how to add silence to the beginning, and this is not what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to drop the file into a DAW like Audacity and make edits manually, then re-render the file.